.Net 8 hosted in Azure App Service get IOException intermittently
I have a function to write log to a text file:
using (var mutex = new Mutex(false, fullPath.Replace("\\", "")))

{

    mutex.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite, false);

    File.AppendAllText(fullPath, content.ToString());

    mutex.ReleaseMutex();

}

The function is called from multiple places, so I use Mutex to make sure only 1 process is accessing the file.
It was working perfectly until I upgraded to .Net 8, I hit the error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." intermittently. Looks like the file is not being released sometimes.
It only happen when I deploy to Azure App Service, it is working fine in my local. Anyone please help...
I thought the AppendAllText is not releasing the file, so I use StreamWriter
            using (var mutex = new Mutex(false, fullPath.Replace("\\", "")))
            {
                mutex.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite, false);

                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fullPath, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(content.ToString());
                    writer.Flush();
                }

                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }

But I still hit the same error.

In Azure App Service, where your application can run on multiple worker instances simultaneously, each instance operates independently with its own processes. As a result, if one instance creates a Mutex for synchronization, it won't be shared or visible to other instances. This lack of synchronization across instances can lead to coordination challenges and potential issues. As a workaround you can directly implement distributed lock and your log file to Azure blob Storage by referring the code below:-
According to this Medium Blog by Veyo Tech using Azure blob lease as a distributed mutex can work.
Azure blob lease code:-
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Azure;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=valleystrg09;AccountKey=F5EhxxxxxxxxxxxxxLaQ==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
        var containerName = "data";
        var blobName = "Test.txt";

        var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
        var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

        
        if (!containerClient.Exists())
        {
            
            await containerClient.CreateAsync();
        }

        var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

        
        if (!blobClient.Exists())
        {
            // Create the blob if it doesn't exist
            await blobClient.UploadAsync(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("")), true);
        }

        try
        {
            
            var blobLeaseClient = blobClient.GetBlobLeaseClient();
            var lease = await blobLeaseClient.AcquireAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
            Console.WriteLine("Lease acquired successfully.");

            
            Console.Write("Enter text to append to the blob: ");
            var content = Console.ReadLine();

            
            var downloadResponse = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(downloadResponse.Value.Content))
            {
                string existingContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                existingContent += content;

                
                await blobClient.UploadAsync(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(existingContent)), true);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Text appended to blob successfully.");
        }
        catch (RequestFailedException ex) when (ex.Status == 412)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to acquire lease: Another process or client already has a lease on the blob.");
        }
    }
}

Output:-

Code 2:-
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlobStorageApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=valleystrg09;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxxjFOe6T0+AStrwuLaQ==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
            string containerName = "data";
            string blobName = "Test.txt"; 

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the content to be added to the blob:");
            string content = Console.ReadLine();

            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)))
            {
                await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, true);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Content uploaded successfully.");
        }
    }
}

Output:-


Thanks for the reply, but it has been working for 3 years before I upgraded to .Net 8. Is this a new feature in .Net 8 only?

Yes, .net 8 does not yet support full features
